# Amazon S3 multipart upload part size via lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a few lambda functions that allow to make a multipart upload to an Amazon S3 bucket. These are responsible for creating the multipart upload, then another one for each part upload and the last one for completing the upload.

First two seem to work fine (they respond with statusCode 200), but the last one fails. On Cloudwatch, I can see an error saying 'Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size'.

This is not true, since I'm uploading files bigger than 5Mb minimum size specified on docs. However, I think the issue is happening in every single part upload.

Why? Because each part only has 2Mb of data. On docs, I can see that every but the last part needs to be at least 5Mb sized. However, when I try to upload parts bigger than 2Mb, I get a CORS error, most probably because I have passed the 6Mb lambda payload limit.

Can anyone help me with this? Below I leave my client-side code, just in case you can see any error on it.

```
setLoading(true);
const file = files[0];
const size = 2000000;
const extension = file.name.substring(file.name.lastIndexOf('.'));
try {
  const multiStartResponse = await startMultiPartUpload({ fileType: extension });
  console.log(multiStartResponse);
  let part = 1;
  let parts = [];
  /* eslint-disable no-await-in-loop */
  for (let start = 0; start < file.size; start += size) {
    const chunk = file.slice(start, start + size + 1);
    const textChunk = await chunk.text();
    const partResponse = await uploadPart({
      file: textChunk,
      fileKey: multiStartResponse.data.Key,
      partNumber: part,
      uploadId: multiStartResponse.data.UploadId,
    });
    console.log(partResponse);
    parts.push({ ETag: partResponse.data.ETag, PartNumber: part });
    part++;
  }
  /* eslint-enable no-await-in-loop */
  const completeResponse = await completeMultiPartUpload({
    fileKey: multiStartResponse.data.Key,
    uploadId: multiStartResponse.data.UploadId,
    parts,
  });
  console.log(completeResponse);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
} finally {
  setLoading(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that uploading parts via lambda is simply not possible, so we need to use a different approach.

Now, our startMultiPartUpload lambda returns not only an upload ID but also a bunch of signedURLs, generated with S3 aws-sdk class, using getSignedUrlPromise method, and 'uploadPart' as operation, as shown below:

```
const getSignedPartURL = (bucket, fileKey, uploadId, partNumber) =>
   s3.getSignedUrlPromise('uploadPart', { Bucket: bucket, Key: fileKey, UploadId: 
   uploadId, PartNumber: partNumber })
```

Also, since uploading a part this way does not return an ETag (or maybe it does, but I just couldn't achieve it), we need to call listParts method on S3 class after uploading each part in order to get those ETags. I'll leave my React code below:

```
const uploadPart = async (url, data) => {
try {
// return await uploadPartToS3(url, data);
return fetch(url, {
  method: 'PUT',
  body: data,
 }).then((e) => e.body);
} catch (e) {
 console.error(e);
 throw new Error('Unknown error');
 }
};

// If file is bigger than 50Mb then perform a multi part upload
const uploadMultiPart = async ({ name, size, originFileObj }, 
 updateUploadingMedia) => {
// chunk size determines each part size. This needs to be > 5Mb
const chunkSize = 60000000;
let chunkStart = 0;
const extension = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('.'));
const partsQuan = Math.ceil(size / chunkSize);
// Start multi part upload. This returns both uploadId and signed urls for each 
part.
const startResponse = await startMultiPartUpload({
  fileType: extension,
  chunksQuan: partsQuan,
});
console.log('start response: ', startResponse);
const {
  signedURLs,
  startUploadResponse: { Key, UploadId },
} = startResponse.data;
try {
  let promises = [];
  /* eslint-disable no-await-in-loop */
  for (let i = 0; i < partsQuan; i++) {
    // Split file into parts and upload each one to it's signed url
    const chunk = await originFileObj.slice(chunkStart, chunkStart + 
   chunkSize).arrayBuffer();
  chunkStart += chunkSize;
  promises.push(uploadPart(signedURLs[i], chunk));
  if (promises.length === 5) {
    await Promise.all(promises);
    promises = [];
  }
  console.log('UPLOAD PART RESPONSE', uploadResponse);
}
/* eslint-enable no-await-in-loop */
// wait until every part is uploaded
await allProgress({ promises, name }, (media) => {
  updateUploadingMedia(media);
});

// Get parts list to build complete request (each upload does not retrieve ETag)
const partsList = await listParts({
  fileKey: Key,
  uploadId: UploadId,
});
// build parts object for complete upload
const completeParts = partsList.data.Parts.map(({ PartNumber, ETag }) => ({
  ETag,
  PartNumber,
}));
// Complete multi part upload
completeMultiPartUpload({
  fileKey: Key,
  uploadId: UploadId,
  parts: completeParts,
});
return Key;
} catch (e) {
  console.error('ERROR', e);
  const abortResponse = await abortUpload({
    fileKey: Key,
    uploadId: UploadId,
  });
  console.error(abortResponse);
}
};
```

Sorry for identation, I corrected it line by line as best as I could :).

Some considerations:

-We use 60Mb chunks because our backend took too long generating all those signed urls for big files.

-Also, this solution is meant to upload really big files, that's why we await every 5 parts.

However, we are stil facing issues to upload huge files (about 35gb) since after uploading 100/120 parts, fetch requests suddenly starts to fail and no more parts are uploaded. If someone knows what's going on, it would be amazing. I publish this as an answer because I think most people will find this very useful.